# Is CorsWhitelistEntry insertable/updatable through APEX/DML?

Tags: apex, dml, cors

```
CorsWhitelistEntry cors = new CorsWhitelistEntry();
cors.UrlPattern = 'sdfsdf.com';
insert cors;
```

Wherever I try the above (or any other DML operation), I get an error message:

> DML operation ... not allowed on CorsWhitelistEntry

Any way to get past this? (I'm aware of REST/SOAP, but I'd really like to do this through APEX)

Comment: The error message itself seems quite descriptive, no? You'll probably have to use callouts.

Comment: @AdrianLarson the problem here is that CorsWhitelistEntry is not on the list of types where DML is disallowed: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_dml_objects.htm

Comment: Hmm...yeah the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_corswhitelistentry.htm?search_text=corswhitelist) indicates `create` is allowed...

Comment: Could it mean it allows DML through Metadata API/Callouts and not Apex coding? Just asking

Answer (score 0):

No,I dont think you can do it through Apex. Try using Metadata API.

Comment: Metadata API works, yes. I'm just asking for people's experience on this.